# Stationary solution of a Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

I have a question that's driving me crazy.

I have a Fokker-Planck equation

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=x\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+D\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}$$

I look for the stationary solution

$$ x\frac{d P}{d x}+D\frac{d^2 P}{d x^2}=0$$

Now, I know that [the solution is](https://github.com/josthijssen/TabletNotes/blob/master/fluctuations_lang.pdf)

$$P(x)=Ce^{-x^2/2D} $$

But I did not understand how to arrive to the solution, because my strategy would be to do a change of variable:

$$xY+D\frac{dY}{d x}=0$$

$$\frac{dP}{d x}=Y$$

So I obtain

$$Y=Y_0 e^{-x^2/2D}$$

$$P=Y_0\int e^{-x^2/2D}dx$$

I am sure that there is something that I miss somewhere, but I do not know where.
Thank you for the help !

EDIT:

To be sure that I understand the multidimensional case:
$$dA=f_1(A,B,C)dt+\sigma_1dW_1$$
$$dB=f_2(A,B,C)dt+\sigma_2dW_2$$
Is the FPE for $P(A,B,t)$
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial f_1 P}{\partial A}-\frac{\partial f_2 P}{\partial B}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_1^2\frac{\partial^2  P}{\partial A^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_2^2\frac{\partial^2  P}{\partial B^2}$$

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2):

The equation you are solving is not the equation that you want to solve. The FPE for the one dimensional autonomous Ito SDE

$$dX=b(X) dt + \sigma(X) dW$$

is

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(b(x) P(x,t))+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left ( \frac{\sigma^2}{2} P(x,t) \right ).$$

In your case, taking $D=1$, $b(x)=-x,\sigma(x)=\sqrt{2}$, so the stationary FPE reads

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x P(x))+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(P(x))=0$$

which does hold with $P(x)=Ce^{-x^2/2}$. You can solve this basically doing what you did in reverse: integrate the derivatives away and then solve a first order linear equation with a constant forcing (but where the constant is unknown). Then use the fact that $P$ must be a probability density to identify the constants of integration.

Comment: Thank you Ian ! One more question. I have a system of three  one dimensional SDE. Do the equations for the three PDF obey to the Fokker Planck equation in your answer ?

Comment: @GV871 Are they coupled? If so then the situation is slightly different but still manageable.

Comment: Yes, they are coupled

Comment: @GV871 When coupled the SDE is $dX=b(X) dt + \sigma(X) dW$ and the FPE reads $\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=-\sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (b_i(x) P(x,t)) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(a_{ij}(x) P(x,t)$ where $a=\sigma \sigma^T$.

Comment: Thank you again @Ian ! One last question. For a system of three equation is the $P$ computed from the FPE  $P(X_1,X_2,X_3,t)$ ?

Comment: @GV871 Yes, it is. Note that it is still a scalar.

Comment: Last question(again), can you look at the expression of $P$ that I have added to the question ?

Comment: @GV871 So first of all I am not confident as to whether the two $dW$ are the same Brownian motion, or independent Brownian motions. In the first case, your *matrix* $\sigma$ is $\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 & 0 \\ \sigma_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ so I think you wind up with what you wrote. In the second case, your matrix $\sigma$ is $\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_2 \end{bmatrix}$ in which case the result is different.

Comment: Actually you are right, the brownian motion are indipendent, I'va corrected the FPE !